# How do I call an ordinary web page from a CGI script?

Tags: html, bash, cgi

I have a CGI script written in bash that performs certain actions and calculations on data passed to it from a parent web page.  It does not display anything on its own page.  When it is complete, I want to launch an ordinary flat HTML web page.  How can I do this without user intervention?  I know, I could create a `submit button or a hyperlink`, but I just want the script to finish its work and then link to a URL all by itself.

Comment: You want to add a redirect header to the script's output?

Comment: Well, that might work, come to think of it, since the web page might not redirect until the script is complete.  I just found another answer, however.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muru had an idea that might work, although there may be instances where it might fail or work in an unexpected manner.  I found a very simple solution, however:

```
curl -s "http://web-page-to-display"
```

I honestly don't know why I did not thnk of it sooner.  It's pretty obvious, really.